# Any infovis ever been tried on stackoverflow data?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, information-display, data-analysis

Today, opening stackoverflow i have read 3 or 4 times the tag QT. For sure is something totally random but this made me think about a friend that this morning talked about how .net is gettin in shadow and c++ is coming back and made me think also about a kind of infovis on stackoverflow data.

Has any infovis about tag trend (for example) ever been tried on stackoverflow?

Speaking about tag trend during the last 3 years for example, have you ever thought about some statistical reduction of data (because I assume that data are too many per hours for making a complete analysis)?

Could you be interested in some kind of project on stackoverflow infovis?

EDIT: thanks to comment i have just found https://data.stackexchange.com/ .. nice place where to start for some infovis! but.. are there some already done good infovis project?

Comment: As long as you don't need very up to date data you can use the data dump and do all the statistical analysis you want on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange recently [had a data-visualization contest](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/10/stack-overflow-data-visualization-contest/) with several interesting entries, including a tag treemap for SO.